# Flutter Android App crashes on restart on Android 12 and below

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

Using Flutter 3.10.6

Hey,
my flutter android application is crashing on restarting the app on Android 12 and below. Android 13 is working fine without any errors. Thats the stacktrace from the app.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000006189f0  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #01  pc 0x00000000003144bc  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #02  pc 0x0000000000314374  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #03  pc 0x0000000000314290  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #04  pc 0x000000000034d65c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #05  pc 0x000000000034cf04  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #06  pc 0x00000000003523c4  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #07  pc 0x000000000035ccec  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #08  pc 0x00000000003f3958  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #09  pc 0x000000000072ab84  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #10  pc 0x000000000072a690  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #11  pc 0x000000000035659c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #12  pc 0x0000000000356540  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #13  pc 0x0000000000354a00  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #14  pc 0x00000000003e3f6c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #15  pc 0x00000000007f7b34  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #16  pc 0x00000000007f79e8  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #17  pc 0x00000000007f0d74  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #18  pc 0x00000000007f080c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #19  pc 0x00000000007f0154  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #20  pc 0x00000000007f011c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #21  pc 0x0000000000318258  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #22  pc 0x0000000000318188  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #23  pc 0x0000000000317d60  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #24  pc 0x0000000000317c18  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #25  pc 0x00000000002e76e0  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #26  pc 0x00000000002e764c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #27  pc 0x00000000002e7600  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #28  pc 0x00000000002e7734  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #29  pc 0x00000000002db3e8  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #30  pc 0x00000000007076c0  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #31  pc 0x000000000083a514  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #32  pc 0x00000000005c384c  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #33  pc 0x00000000005b6578  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #34  pc 0x00000000005cb9d0  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #35  pc 0x0000000000352b50  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #36  pc 0x0000000000355fcc  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #37  pc 0x0000000000016bb0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+912)
  #38  pc 0x00000000000167b8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112)
  #39  pc 0x0000000000017284  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100)
  #40  pc 0x00000000003560d8  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #41  pc 0x0000000000354710  /data/app/~~dDWtyCIxlwEbhf7BIFq0pA==/com.example.test-YUAqbP8e3wJSx6SBL6BNUw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
  #42  pc 0x00000000000ecb58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264)
  #43  pc 0x000000000008ae88  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I upgraded the Gradle version from 7.1.2 to 7.3.1 with the Android Studio AGP but still get the error.

Comment: The log you posted is useless by the way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.